# Vote Early, Vote Often!

Tags: discussion, voting

I would like to echo [a post that Scott Morrison made on Meta.Tex.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/vote-early-and-often):

> I'm a moderator from MathOverflow, and this "question" is actually unsolicited advice, based on our experience from the initial launch of MathOverflow.
>
> > We should encourage everyone to vote positively as often as possible!
>
> Every Stack Exchange site will eventually end up with a different "base level" of voting --- that is, the expected number of upvotes for a question of a given level of excellence. (This effect occurs because people see a good question, but already with a certain number of votes, and think "oh, I would have upvoted this, but it already has enough".)
>
> It's easy for us to affect this "base level" by encouraging high levels of upvoting now. We're setting the standards, and this really will have an effect.
>
> (On MathOverflow, we were very active about this early on, specifically encouraging all the initial round of users to vote early and often. You can compare statistics, and see that the average vote total for a MathOverflow question is much higher than on any of the other SE 1.0 sites.)
>
> In case it's not obvious: the rationale for wanting this base level to be high is that it provides better positive feedback to good contributors."

Especially in the beginning, let us vote early, and vote often.

Comment: Consider this post upvoted.

Comment: Voting for the sake of voting defeats the purpose of voting.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker has a point: Please do make judicious use of downvotes as a method of quality control as well! (i.e. don't upvote every single post you see)

Comment: It's my impression that downvotes should only be used when an answer is either *wrong* or *unproductive*.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Byron That's how I see it. IMHO a downvote rate of more than 2-3% is way too much (spam excluded of course, however, these downvotes don't make it in your statistics once the post is removed). People should downvote really only answers that are clearly malacious or blatantly bad, and questions that show a serious lack of effort (and not a lack of understanding how SE works). And remember: A downvote without a comment is a useless nonsense.

Comment: I regularly upvote most questions found here because I read them often and they are useful for me. Unproductive, duplicate, rude questions/answer are rare to find here. Overall, I find most of this site content to be useful in some way or other and productive for me. :)